# Wordpress admin - Where in database is it set?

Tags: database, wordpress, admin

I'm looking to grab admin user emails to use within a contact form. I have 2 admins that I've assigned. I'd like to grab them from the database. Where is/what is the designation point that I can use when I make the sql statment?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following

```
global $wpdb;
//comma separated list
$admins=$wpdb->get_var('select group_concat(`user_email`) as `admin_emails` from `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'users` as `users` inner join `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'usermeta` as `usermeta` on `usermeta`.`user_id`=`users`.`ID` where `meta_key`=\'wp_user_level\' and `meta_value` in (8,9,10);');
//array of associated arrays
$admins=$wpdb->get_results('select `user_email` from `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'users` as `users` inner join `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'usermeta` as `usermeta` on `usermeta`.`user_id`=`users`.`ID` where `meta_key`=\'wp_user_level\' and `meta_value` in (8,9,10);', ARRAY_A);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php $user_info = get_userdata(1);
      echo 'Username: ' . $user_info->user_login . "\n";
      echo 'User roles: ' . implode(', ', $user_info->roles) . "\n";
      echo 'User ID: ' . $user_info->ID . "\n";
  ?>
      You can pass the User id herer.....
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to create the function. To do so, paste the following code in your functions.php file:

```
function getUsersByRole($role) {
      $wp_user_search = new WP_User_Search($usersearch, $userspage, $role);
      return $wp_user_search->get_results();
}
```

Once done, you can call the function this way:

```
$editors = getUsersByRole('Administrator');
foreach($editors as $editor){
     //$editor now holds the user ID of an editor
}
```